# linux system function

Tags: c++

Below is a program i have written that ran  fine when I type what linux command I wanted it to perform

```
include iostream
include string 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "The directory!";   

    system("cd CS_204");

    return 0;
}
```

However below I tried to make it so a user can type in the command that they wanted and I get they can not convert `std::string` to `const char*` This is my first time using the function and I am desperately trying to understand it. Help!!

```
int main()
{
    cout << "The directory!"; 

    string word;


    cin >> word

    if(word != "A")
        system(word);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second case, `word` is of type **std::string** and is not equivalent to **const char*** . You need to get the c-style string using the member function [std::string::c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

```
system(word.c_str());  // This will convert to a c style string.
```

Comment: Thank you both so much and I will remember to tag it as homework next time sorry! But thanks!!!